# IronSource proguard obfuscation rules

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, ironsource

There is an app with IronSource integration. APK release version build, install and use is absolutely fine. But when I build AAB file, upload it to Google Play console and install it on device, it crashes. I've tried `-dontobfuscate` in proguard rules and it fixes the problem but I need obfuscation of my main `core` module. What rules should I add to proguard configuration?

StackTrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:614)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:168)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:185)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.utils.IronSourceUtils.b(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.utils.IronSourceUtils.getCachedValueByKeyOfCachedInitResponse(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.utils.IronSourceUtils.isInitResponseCached(Unknown Source:3)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.y.q(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.y.a(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.IronSource.init(Unknown Source:4)
    at n2.d$a.run(PluginAds.java:88)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to Pangle ad network. Without it everything works even with obfuscation.